# Stanford Stanza NLP to networkx: superimpose NER entities onto graph of words

Tags: python, nlp, networkx, stanford-nlp

Here is a sample program which will take a text (example is in italian but Stanza supports many languages) and builds and displays a graph of the words (only certain Parts of Speech) and their syntactic relationships:

```
"""
Sample program to analyze a phrase with Stanfords STANZA and
build a networkx graph selecting certain token types
"""
import stanza
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

IN_TXT = "All'ippica disse nel 1999 Ignazio Larussa. Poi a Taranto svenne!"
LANG = "it"
ALLOWED_POS = ["NOUN", "PROPN", "VERB"]
NXDOPTS = {
    "node_color": "orange",
    "edge_color": "powderblue",
    "node_size": 400,
    "width": 2,
}


# download appropriate language model
stanza.download(LANG, verbose=False)
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(
    LANG,
    processors="tokenize, pos, lemma, mwt, ner, depparse",
    verbose=False,
    use_gpu=False,
)
# generate a STANZA document from the given text via the pipeline
doc = nlp(IN_TXT)


for sentence in doc.sentences:
    # initialize G as MultiDiGraph for every sentence
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    # fill the graph with the relevant data
    G.add_node(0, id=0, text="ROOT", lemma="ROOT", upos="ROOT")  # fictitious ROOT node
    for word in [w for w in sentence.words if w.pos in ALLOWED_POS]:
        wordict = word.to_dict()
        G.add_node(wordict["id"], **wordict)
        G.add_edge(wordict["id"], wordict["head"], label=wordict["deprel"])
    # compute graph drawing parameters
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    nodelabels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, "text")
    edgelabels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "label")
    # and now display the graphs
    nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, labels=nodelabels, **NXDOPTS)
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edgelabels)
    plt.margins(0.2)
    plt.suptitle(sentence.text)
    plt.show()
    # clear the graph to repeat for another sentence
    G.clear()
```

and here is the resulting graph:
[image]
The NLP pipeline also performs a NER on the same text and here are the two recognized name entities (a person and a place:

```
[{
  "text": "Ignazio Larussa",
  "type": "PER",
  "start_char": 26,
  "end_char": 41
}, {
  "text": "Taranto",
  "type": "LOC",
  "start_char": 49,
  "end_char": 56
}]
```

I would like to be able to map these two on the graph above.

In Taranto's case where the NER span equals the word span, I guess I just need to map the NER span onto the right word start and end chars.

In "Ignazio Larussa"'s case things are more tricky, since the NER span encompasses TWO words. So in this case I want to show only ONE node with the NER span "Ignazio Larussa" connected via the nsubj edge to the "disse" verb.

How would you handle networkx G graph to achieve this? Thanks a lot